# Why a lost reference to variable in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have a component that has input data:

```
<app-order-applications-list *ngSwitchCase="'DOCATTACH'" [applications]="block?.datasource?.value"></app-order-applications-list>
```

Component is:

```
export class OrderApplicationsListComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() applications: OrderApplicationUI[] = [];
     ngOnInit(): void {
        this.applications = this.applications.map((app, index) => {
            return { ...app, index: ++index };
        });
    }
}

 public select(app: OrderApplicationUI): void {
        app.selected = !app.selected;
        console.log(app);
}
```

when I changed `app.selected = !app.selected;` it has no effect to input `@Input() applications: OrderApplicationUI[] = [];` why?

Template is:

```
  <div
        class="example-box"
        [ngClass]="{ 'example-list__selected': app.selected }"
        *ngFor="let app of applications"
        (click)="select(app)"
        cdkDrag
    >
```

I have changed this code on this:

```
   this.applications = this.applications.map((app, index) => {
            app.index = ++index;
            app.selected = false;
            return app;
        });
```

Now it works, could you please explain why?

Comment: Maybe problem is in ` this.applications.map`?

Comment: See my updated question, please

Comment: You are deconstructing your object into a new one in the first one. In the changed code you update the object and return that. So the reference stays.

Comment: How to make this shortly?

Comment: Why are you reassigning. As you are only updating fields you should just loop over and add to your index/ set to false. TL;DR Don't use map, just loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you change the `app.selected = !app.selected` you change the value of a property from your `@input` variable.

To trigger the change you should change the reference of your property.
If the property is not an object or array that should work OK but when it's not that case
like your example, the change will not be trigger unless you change the reference of the value like you did in your second try.

In other words you need a new array to trigger the input change.